# Cant see mining reuslt on ethermine

Tags: mining, mining-pools, claymore, solo-mining

I've been trying different kinds of mining.
I've tried to mine on windows using Claymore which, as I understand, uses a mining pool. After running for 1 hour, I can go to `https://ethermine.org/miners/<my_adress>` and see that I have a very very small "unpaid balance" and that the graphs are showing some output.

I've also mined on AWS following [this](https://github.com/angelomilan/ethereum-guides/blob/master/GPU-cloud_mining.md) tutorial using a more powerfull g3 instance. I presume Im minuing because I see output like this:

```
miner  22:54:10.327|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #fd6bf22e… : 10689366 H/s = 5505024 hashes / 0.515 s
miner  22:54:10.849|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #fd6bf22e… : 11069420 H/s = 5767168 hashes / 0.521 s
miner  22:54:11.370|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #fd6bf22e… : 10566264 H/s = 5505024 hashes / 0.521 s
miner  22:54:11.885|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #fd6bf22e… : 11198384 H/s = 5767168 hashes / 0.515 s
miner  22:54:12.396|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #fd6bf22e… : 10794164 H/s = 5505024 hashes / 0.51 s
miner  22:54:12.925|ethminer  Mining on PoWhash #fd6bf22e… : 10902018 H/s = 5767168 hashes / 0.529 s
```

After 4 hours running, if I go to `https://ethermine.org/miners/<my_adress>` (its a different account than the one I using on windows), I dont see anything - no ether, no graphs.

My guess is that, on windows I joined a mining pool so Im getting very little reward for very litlle work and on AWS Im doing solo mining and wasnt able to mine anything yet. However, IM affraid that there may be something wrong on my AWS config and the ETH is not going to my account.

Does anyone know what's the case?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide some more details of the config you've got for AWS.

Comment: hey, what else do you need to know? I've got ethminer running like so: "ethminer -G --opencl-device 0" and geth running like so: "geth --rpc --mine --etherbase <my_adress>"